# Can mathematics be sublime?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, aesthetics

The [Sublime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_(philosophy)) is sometime used as a synonym for subtle or sophisticated but with aesthetic overtones. In the original setting for this aesthetic notion it was a combination of Beauty & Greatness, and it evolved to also include Awe & Terror & Horror. For example Kant held that

> the sublime was of three kinds: the noble, the splendid, and the terrifying.

Mathematics is commonly held (by mathematicians and others - for example Rexroth a poet, and Pasternak a novelist and poet) to have Beauty; can it also be sublime in all of Kants sense?

Sublime in the [16th century](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sublime) was generally understood to mean as:

> "expressing lofty ideas in an elevated manner," from Middle French sublime (15c.), or directly from Latin sublimis "uplifted, high, borne aloft, lofty, exalted, eminent, distinguished," possibly originally "sloping up to the lintel," from sub "up to" + limen "lintel, threshold, sill".

Comment: Surely math has inspired its share of awe, terror, and horror in generations of students.

Comment: [Ordinal numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrdinalNumber.html) and [cardinal numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CardinalNumber.html) are good candidates to be subtle terrorists; [fractal sets](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MandelbrotSet.html) are horrible in their beauty...

Comment: Can mathematics be sublime?  Only if you are doing it right!

Comment: @NickR I believe that if you froze a mathematician and set him loose in the vacuum of space, he would sublime. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublimation_(phase_transition)

Comment: @user4894 Yes, and he would no doubt be expressible in sublime mathematical terms.

Comment: Of course, but, with all due respect, the question is very simple. Given one instance of a person experiencing awe in the face of a mathematical result, it is determined that mathematics can be sublime (arguably). I know of one such instance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can argue that mathematics can be sublime based on how mathematics is able to invoke emotions and inspire even those who aren't directly involved with solving the equations.

To give a few examples, I would argue that [Conway's game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) as a mathematical topic is able to demonstrate how complex patterns can develop out of simple rules.

Similarly [the Mandelbrot Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) shows us an abstract and beautiful pattern resulting from the continous application of a simple rule, which I at least for my own part find inspiring similarly to a work of art in it's reflection on how complex patterns in the world around me may arise from simple things.

In the realm of number theory, primes and pi have inspired people for centuries, not just because of their mathematical properties but also by virtue of an unpredictable behaviour (pi is irrational, primes are hard to predict) emerging from a deterministic system. Classically this unpredictable behaviour was so frightening to the Pythagoreans that they supposedly resorted to [drowing Hippasus when he proved the irrationality of sqrt(2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippasus#Irrational_numbers) although this is probably not entirely based on reality.

Whether these examples are enought to justify mathematics as sublime is up to you to decide, but I think it's fair to conclude that mathematics is able to both *inspire*, *frighten*, and *amaze*.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematics is the fundamental programming code of reality. It is without doubt that reality is both grotesque and exquisite. It therefore reasons that mathematics is sublime,in essence reality is sublime.